# Scotch-io/node-todo app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

How is the index.html (frontend Angular) getting called exactly?

In the tutorial, it was said that by having one of the following routes in route.js, frontend is getting called

`app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); 
     });`

----------or-------------------

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile('__dirname + '/public/index.html'); 
 });
```

But even after removing that route, index.html is getting opened (or) If I rename index.html as index1.html at route and html file it is showing error.

Comment: Basically, public is like root folder & index.html is the default file which will be called when a request is coming to the server. But if there is not index.html file in your root folder, it will be never called. Then you can use route to render specified file.

Comment: Thanks @rroxysam, it should call index1.html if I change in the route from index.html.Then it showing the path gave is wrong like                                     Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\SESA429579\Downloads\Application2\app\public\index1.html'
   at Error (native)                        Why is that happening?

Comment: Have you created a file index1.html in public folder?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a file index1.html in public folder? If yes, Use

```
 res.sendfile('public/index1.html');
```

OR

```
var path = require('path');
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index1.html'));
```

to render index1.html.

Note : **sendfile is deprecated.**